# String(contentsOf: URL) returns "No such file or directory"

Tags: swift, macos

I am a swift beginner and I am trying to write a function that reads the contents of a *.csv file and return a 2-D array [[Double]].

I am using Xcode 10.1 running on macOS 10.14.

I am using the following code (in a playground) to read the contents of the file into a String:

```
let home = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser // 

let file = "Documents⁩/MyAppName⁩/x.csv"

let url = home.appendingPathComponent(file)

url.path // This gives: "/Users/userName/Documents⁩/MyAppName⁩/x.csv"

let s = try String(contentsOf: url)
```

I get the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “x.csv” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/userName/Documents⁩/MyAppName⁩/x.csv, NSUnderlyingError=0x7febf3c991b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

I know this is probably something ridiculously simple I am forgetting but I looked a lot for a solution and I couldn't find one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Barring that, does the playground allow you to read arbitrary files from the file system? I know that whenever I write an app to read a file, it always fails and  then I have to add an entitlement for reading files.

Comment: @user1118321: I tried running it in a terminal app but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
let file = "Documents⁩/MyAppName⁩/x.csv"
```

You can't see it but between the `s` and `/` there is a hidden character - U+2069 - "POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE". Retype that line again without any special characters and your code will work.

That aside, here is how you should create the URL to the Documents folder.

```
let home = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

let file = "MyAppName⁩/x.csv"
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works despite the output of `path` appearing the same? This is fairly surprising to me.

Comment: @user1118321 I'm trying to figure that out myself. But in the meantime, the code in my answer is the proper way to get access to a user's Documents folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Unfortunately, I tried this but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I just updated my answer for the real problem. Please see the update.

Comment: How did a hidden character got inserted? And what can I do to make sure it is not inserted?

Comment: There's no way to know how it got there. Perhaps you were working with some RTL text or something.

Comment: @user1118321 As you can see from my updated answer, my original answer worked simply because I unknowingly removed the hidden character.

Comment: Oh wow! That's crazy! Good catch! I once had a problem where Xcode (or really any app, but it was only a problem in Xcode)  would insert an invisible Cntl-P into my document whenever I hit the Windows key of the Windows keyboard I had connected to my Mac. Furthermore, Xcode didn't render anything for that character. I don't recall how I eventually figured out what was going on, but it was a hair-pulling experience!

Comment: @rmaddy How the hell did you catch that?

Comment: @Alexander I thought the problem was how the path was built. I copied the original code into my playground, changed the value of `file` to one I actually have in my Documents folder and I got the same error. So I changed the way Documents was accessed and updated `file` by removing the "Documents/" part. And it worked. For some reason I then put back the original `home` line and retyped the "Documents/" part (essentially recreating the original code), and surprisingly it worked again. Then I realized there must be something hiding in the OP's original string. Some debugging showed it.

Comment: @rmaddy Impressive catch. Reminds me of all those "greek question mark" pranks.

Comment: You can also see it if you copy-paste that line into a text editor, such as BBEdit. In fact, there seems to be another hidden character, right after MyAppName.

Comment: I think the problem is that I copied the path from finder by right-clicking on the file and going to show info. For some reason, when I did that, every slash was preceded with hidden characters.